# How to set External IP in double nat network?

Tags: networking, router, nat

So I have 2 routers:

> 1.T-Mobile B525s-23a
>   2.Asus RT-AC58U

My setup is

```
Internet -- B525s-23a ------ Asus RT-AC58U ------ devices
```

I want to enable **DDNS** on Asus RT-AC58U but it gets assigned private **WAN IP** so it does not work.

I dont really know how to assing my external ip to RT-AC58U. I read about DMZ on google but Tmobile router does not support that.

What can I do to get **External IP** on RT-AC58U to enable DDNS?

Comment: Do you need the two routers, or would putting the B525s-23a into "_bridge mode_" work for your use-case? (note: it appears that bridge mode was removed from the firmware at some point, you may have an older version, or it may have been added in again since).

Comment: Well I need 2 routers but bridge mode is not available on this router

Comment: It likely _won't be_ available with an LTE connection, as LTE is not Ethernet-like, but does it have anything like "passthrough mode" instead?

Comment: No, I bouth it only to connenct antenna and get RSSI,RSQ-something to set it up properly. Asus is very managable and I;m using it as "Main" router. Now I wanted to setup access to one of devices on the network using DDNS but I realised that Tmobile router does not really have any passthrough,bridge,DMZ options

Comment: Also if that helps DDNS is available on Tmobile router but then I still cant access devices in network cause they are on other ip-range.

Comment: Double NAT means double port forwarding. There is absoluty no way around that. I’m not sure what exactly you’re expecting? DDNS just makes a domain point at an IP address. That IP address must be internet-routable, so it cannot be the Asus router’s address. Does your T-Mobile router even have a public IP address?

Comment: No, but it has enabled ddns

Comment: If you don’t have a public IP address, you won’t be able to receive incoming connections. DDNS is entirely unrelated.

Comment: Ok,thanks for help, if you could post it as answer then I mark it

Answer (score 0):

According to your information, you cannot setup DDNS via the routers, as the one
connected to the internet does not support neither DDNS nor bridge-mode.

You need therefore to set it up on the computer using third-party software.

An example free provider of DDNS is
[Duck DNS](https://www.duckdns.org/):

> Duck DNS is a provider of what is known as a DDNS (Dynamic DNS)
>   service we provide a public DNS server that anyone can get a subdomain
>   and use one of our provided scripts to update their record(s). so
>   instead of trying to remember an IP address, you can use a domain name
>   that is kept up-to-date by a computer at home
>
> once this is done, periodically (usually every 5 minutes), the
>   computer running the client, tells our central system (via a HTTPS
>   post), to update the record with its latest external IP.

[NO-IP](https://www.noip.com/remote-access/?utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=international&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI7ZG1jLrq6QIVmojVCh2RowVtEAAYASAAEgIFkvD_BwE)
is another example of free provider of DDNS having a Windows client.
However, the free account will nag you every month for confirmation of your
DNS address.

Comment: I have DDNS on Tmobile router(which is the one that is connected to internet)

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: I CAN enable DDNS on tmobiel router. TMobile router is connected to WAN port of ASUS and devices are connected to ASUS router and I want to access devices from ASUS router over ddns

Comment: You mean loopback : device->router->internet->router->device? This is only possible with some specific routers or with advanced third-party firmware.

Comment: No, look at my post. I have internet-router-router2-device and I want to connect to device from internet(DDNS)

Comment: In other words: local->internet->local via the same router(s). Same remark applies. Use your phone or something so as not to pass through the same routers.

Comment: The post doesn't really express what you want but is rather an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: In my post "What can I do to get External IP on RT-AC58U to enable DDNS?" and also other thing in my post "I want to enable DDNS on Asus RT-AC58U"

Answer (score 0):

*You indicate you do not have an internet-routable IP address. You will not be able to receive incoming (unsolicited) traffic.*

This is not surprising. Most mobile broadband services use [carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) because there’s simply not enough IPv4 addresses available.

---

Dynamic DNS (DDNS) is just one thing: Fancy names for (dynamic) IP addresses. So instead of having to deal with IP addresses or even changing IP addresses, you have a fixed name to remember and pass to others. It does not solve or involve port forwarding or anything else.

If you had a public IP address, you’d want to use the DDNS client on the outermost router. Alternative, you could also use a DDNS client that auto-detects the external (public) IP address. This is a feature typically found in PC DDNS clients expected to be deployed behind NAT routers.

In your setup, you’d still need to create all port forwardings twice (though an exposed host setting, colloquially “DMZ”, could simplify things somewhat).